# MOSFET power wattage

Tags: power, mosfet, thermal

I am analyzing the thermal dissipation of the FDB33N25 MOSFET - [datasheet](https://www.soselectronic.com/productdata/13/00/25/130025/FDB33N25.pdf)

The procedure I usually follow is as stated:

$$I_{d} = 15~A (requirement)$$
$$R_{ds} = 92~m\Omega$$
$$\Theta_{ja} = 62,5~K/W$$
$$P = I^2 \cdot R_{ds} = 20,7~W$$
$$T = P \cdot \Theta_{ja} = 20,7 \cdot 62,5 = 1293~K$$

The MOSFET can sustain a max of 20 A. So 15 A should be fine. But the temperature generated is mind blowing.

Is this analysis correct? If yes, then I can never achive 15 A without extravagant cooling. Also, will this temp of 1293 K be in the ambient space (theoretically of course)?

Comment: Rthja = 62.5 Celsius/Watt tell us that for every 1 watt of power dissipation in the MOSFET the junction temperature will rise 62.5 celsius above the ambient temperature. And welcome in the real world. http://www.mcmanis.com/chuck/robotics/projects/esc2/FET-power.html And Rthja is a thermal resistance between junction and ambient without any additional heat sink

Comment: You used the Rth junction-ambient figure, which is applicable when you don't use any heatsinking at all. The max figures, especially the marketing-department-written ones on the first page of a datasheet, assume the most favourable situation, in this case an unlimited heatsink.

Comment: @ThePhoton it's actually (i)x(i)xRds. Sorry about the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thermal Resistance, Junction-to-Case, Max. 0.53 °C/W

So, if you could stick a 2°C/W heat sink on your D2PAK, it would dissipate 20W without problems. I suspect you will find this rather difficult though, so here are other solutions:

- FET with lower RdsON
- FET with a more heat-sink friendly package
- Several FETs in parallel

The last one allows both to lower the dissipation, and to spread it between several packages, where it will be easier to dissipate.

**Important Note:** Since you selected a 250V MOSFET, I'm assuming you need the voltage rating. If this is a low voltage application, you will get much better RdsON with an appropriate choice of lower-voltage MOSFET.

Answer (score 0):

What is your applied gate-drain voltage.

RdsON is a fickle number that has a number of dependent variables. Do not just rely on the front sheet marketing number.. Check the graphs.

Your gate voltage may be insufficient.

And yes.. 20W = LARGE HEATSINK. 62.5 Celcius/Watt is for the device package to air on it's own.

You should also consider looking for a better MOSFET. 92mOhs is not that great these days. It also increases with temperature, so dumping heat is very important.

Comment: BTW I was going to show you a better MOSFET example, but you did not list your REAL voltage requirement.